# Don't apply the tag limit to moderator-only tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, moderator-tags, tag-limit

I've come across [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277076/give-mods-communities-better-tools-for-large-retagging-jobs) in the featured tab. It already has the maximum 5 tags, so there is no room for a status tag. It seems that it either must stay as it is with no status tags, or one of the tags must be removed to allow room for a status tag. This seems a little bit pointless, since all it's tags relate to the question.

To solve this, the limit of 5 tags could be removed for moderator-only tags in order to be able to place status tags on questions that already have 5 tags.

Comment: IMO, this will  be feasible only if the status won't be set as a tag but as a banner, with the title itself changed, like it's doing today with closed questions. (i.e. the status change won't be direct part of the question.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's reasonably common that (even without a status-* tag) you can find six or more tags that apply to a question. However, in most cases, only two or three are essential.

In your case, the [ambiguous-tags](/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags) and [meta-tags](/questions/tagged/meta-tags) tags can certainly be missed; in fact, a new tag for questions *about* [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)s would IMHO be more appropriate. (This tag itself is already used for actual retag requests, most of which should be closed/migrated away to Meta Stack Overflow because they're about Stack Overflow, but I digress).

A good way to see this is the number of watchers. [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) has 55, [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) has 32, while the other two have 3 and 7. There might be some people actively following those tags, but it's also likely that they misclicked the old 'favorite' and/or the new 'Watch Tag' button.

Comment: It's also likely that several people watched [\*tags\*], and thus wildcarded their way into the watched tags list.

Comment: Maybe *meta-retag-request* (like [meta-faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-faq))?

Comment: That, or [retag-request-process], like [tag:feature-request-process].

Comment: [retag-request-process] sounds good and a bit clearer.